# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, illegalstateexception

Please, I've a problem. I want to get all entities on web api(`news.api`)

But I've an execution error while `retrofit` response:

**Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 57**

Thanks for your help

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("top-headlines")
    Call<ResponseNewsApi> getResponseNewsApi(@Query("sources") String source, @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);

}

public class ResponseNewsApi {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("totalResults")
    private String totalResults;
    @SerializedName("articles")
    private List<Post> articles;
}

public class Post {

    @SerializedName("source")
    private List<String> source;

    @SerializedName("author")
    private String author;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;

    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    private String urlToImage;

    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    private String publishedAt;

    @SerializedName("content")
    private String content;
}

service.getResponseNewsApi(source,apiKey).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseNewsApi>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseNewsApi> call, Response<ResponseNewsApi> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse response:: " + response);
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    data.setValue(response.body());
                    Log.d(TAG, "posts total result:: " + response.body().getTotalResults());
                    Log.d(TAG, "posts size:: " + response.body().getArticles().size());
                    Log.d(TAG, "posts title pos 0:: " + response.body().getArticles().get(0).getTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseNewsApi> call, Throwable t) {
                data.setValue(null);
                Log.e(TAG,"Error get enqueue Retrofit");
                Log.e(TAG,"Error: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        return data;
```

Comment: What 's the actual JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this exception because you are using  `List<String> source` in your `Post` class means you want `source` as an `array` but in your `JSON` response it is an `Object`. so you have to change it to an `object`.

Make a class for your source object like the following.

```
 public class Source {
    private String id;
    private String name;
 }
```

And now You have to change `source` type in `Post` class like the following

```
@SerializedName("source")
 //private List<String> source;
 private Source source; // source is an object in your response json
```